# Como lograr poner Mayúscula en los campos de tipo Entry y Formatear números en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Cordial saludo a todos.

Tengo un pequeño código en Python en el cual estoy capturando unos campos para agregarlos abajo en un Treeview, y me gustaría por favor saber como hacer lo siguiente (soy principiante en esto):

1. Lograr que lo que se ingrese en el campo "name" (Entry) de mi formulario quede siempre en mayúscula. He tratado de usar la función "upper()", pero me sale error.
2. Así mismo que lo que se capture en el campo "precio", quede con su separador de miles y el formato de moneda respectivo, y así se refleje igual abajo en la tabla.

Les dejo mi código y copia de la base de datos de prueba Aqui. Gracias.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

# ------------- APLICACION DE PRODUCTOS--------------

# 1 - CREACION CLASE PRODUCT PARA MANEJAR TODAS LAS VENTANAS Y METODOS DE LA APLICACION DE PRODUCTOS
class Product:
    # 8 - CREAR VARIABLE PARA BD
    db_name = 'database.db'

    # 4 - DEFINIMOS EL CONSTRUCTOR Y TOMAMOS EL PARAMETRO QUE NOS ESTAN PASANDO AL INICIAR LA VENTANA
    def __init__(self, window):

        # 6 - CREAR PROPIEDAD U OBJETO PARA ALMACENAR LA VENTANA QUE ESTA RECIBIENDO EL CONSTRUCTOR
        self.win = window
        self.win.title('Aplicacion de Productos')

        self.interfaz_inicial()

        # BOTON AGREGAR PRODUCTO
        ttk.Button(frame, text='AGREGAR PRODUCTO', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2, ipadx=40, pady = 10)

        # LABEL PARA MENSAJES DE SALIDA
        self.message = Label(text = '')
        self.message.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E, padx = 150)

        # TABLA
        frame2 = LabelFrame(self.win, text=' LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS: ')
        frame2.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 20, pady = 15)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame2, height = 10, columns=("#1", "#2", "#"))
        self.tree.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 10)
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="Nombre", anchor = CENTER)         
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Precio", anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Stock", anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="Seccion", anchor = CENTER)

        # SCROLL VERTICAL TREEVIEW
        scrolvert = Scrollbar(frame2, command = self.tree.yview)
        scrolvert.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=scrolvert.set)

         # SCROLL HORIZONTAL TREEVIEW
        scrolhoriz = Scrollbar(frame2, command = self.tree.xview, orient='horizontal')
        scrolhoriz.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="news")
        self.tree.config(xscrollcommand=scrolhoriz.set)

        # BOTONES
        ttk.Button(text='EDIT', command=self.edit_product).grid(row = 13, column = 0, columnspan=2, ipadx = 50, pady = 10)
        ttk.Button(text='DELETE', command=self.del_product).grid(row = 13, column = 1, columnspan=2, ipadx = 50, pady = 10)

        self.get_products()

    # 7 - CREACION INTERFAZ GRAFICA
    def interfaz_inicial(self):

        global frame
        # FUNCION PARA TRANSFORMAR A MAYUSCULA

        # FRAME CONTENEDOR
        frame = LabelFrame(self.win, text=' REGISTRAR UN NUEVO PRODUCTO: ')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 15, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)

        # INPUT NAME
        Label(frame, text=' Nombre: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        #self.name = Entry(frame, width=45)
        self.name = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.name.focus()

        # INPUT PRECIO
        Label(frame, text=' Precio: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        #self.price = Entry(frame, width=25)
        #self.price = UpperEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.price = CurrencyEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # INPUT STOCK
        Label(frame, text=' Stock: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        #self.stock = Entry(frame, width=25)
        self.stock = UpperEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.stock.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # INPUT SECCION
        Label(frame, text=' Seccion: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        #self.section = Entry(frame, width=45)
        self.section = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
        self.section.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # BOTON AGREGAR PRODUCTO
        ttk.Button(frame, text='AGREGAR PRODUCTO', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2, ipadx=40, pady = 10)

    # 9 - CREAR METODO PARA CONECTAR Y HACER CONSULTAS A LA BASE DE DATOS
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    # 10 - OBTENER DATOS DE LA TABLA product
    def get_products(self):

        #limpiando treeview
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)

        # ejeutando consulta    
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)

        # llenando data
        for row in db_rows:
            #print(row)
            self.tree.insert('',0,text = row[1], values = (row[2], row[3], row[4]))

    # 11 - VALIDAR CAMPOS

    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get()) != 0  and len(self.price.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.section.get()) != 0

    # 12 - AGREGAR PRODUCTOS
    def add_product(self):

        if self.validation():

            query = 'INSERT INTO product VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get(), self.stock.get(), self.section.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'El Producto {} ha sido agregado!!'.format(self.name.get())
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#d4edda'
            self.message['fg'] ='#116158'
            # LIMPIAR CAMPOS
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.price.delete(0, END)
            self.stock.delete(0, END)
            self.section.delete(0, END)
            self.name.focus()

        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Todos los campos son requeridos...'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()

        self.get_products()

    # 13 - ELIMINAR PRODUCTOS
    def del_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''    
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name,))
        self.message['text'] = 'El Producto {} ha sido eliminado!!'.format(name)
        self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
        self.message['bg'] ='#d4edda'
        self.message['fg'] ='#116158'
        self.name.focus()
        self.get_products()

    # 14 - EDITAR PRODUCTOS
    def edit_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        nuevo = Entry()
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()
            return
        name1 = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar(frame, value=name1)).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

    # 2 - LANZAR APLICACION

class UpperEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self._var = kwargs.get("textvariable") or StringVar(parent)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._to_upper()

    def config(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        self.configue(cnf, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        var = kwargs.get("textvariable")
        if var is not None:
            var.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = var
        super().config(cnf, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key == "textvariable":
            item.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = item
        super.__setitem__(key, item)

    def _to_upper(self, *args):
        self._var.set(self._var.get().upper())

class CurrencyEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(
            self, parent, *args,
            currency_symbol="€", thousand_sep=".", decimal_sep=",", **kwargs
            ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(
            highlightbackground="#000000", highlightcolor="#000000",
            highlightthickness=1, relief=FLAT
            )
        self._int_var = StringVar(self)
        self._dec_var = StringVar(self)
        vcmd_int = (self.register(self.on_validate_int), '%S')
        vcmd_dec = (self.register(self.on_validate_dec), '%S')
        self._thousand_sep = thousand_sep
        self._decimal_sep = decimal_sep
        self._int_entry = Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._int_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_int,
            borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT, justify='right',
            width=15, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._int_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x")

        self._dec_label = Label(
            self, text=decimal_sep, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._dec_entry = Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._dec_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_dec,
            borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT, width=2,
            highlightthickness=0
        )

        self._sym_label = Label(
            self, text=currency_symbol, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._sym_label.pack(side="left")

        self._int_last_index = True
        self._dec_first_index = False
        self._int_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_int_release)
        self._dec_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_dec_release)

    def on_validate_int(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789" and char != self._decimal_sep:
            return False
        return True

    def on_validate_dec(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789":
            return False
        return True

    def _on_int_release(self, event):
        if self._int_entry.index(INSERT) == self._int_entry.index(END):
            if self._int_last_index and event.keysym == "Right":
                self._last_index = False
                self._dec_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._int_last_index = True
        else:
            self._int_last_index = False

        text = self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, "")
        if self._decimal_sep in text:
            int_, dec = text.split(self._decimal_sep)
            self._int_var.set(int_)
            self._sym_label.pack_forget()
            self._dec_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_entry.pack(side="left")
            self._sym_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_var.set(dec[:2])
            self._dec_entry.focus_set()
        self.set_thousand_sep()

    def _on_dec_release(self, event):
        key = event.keysym
        if key == "Left" and self._dec_entry.index(INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_first_index = False
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._dec_first_index = True

        elif key == "BackSpace" and self._dec_entry.index(INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_label.pack_forget()
                if self._dec_var.get() and int(self._dec_var.get()):
                    self._int_var.set(
                        self._int_var.get() + self._dec_var.get()
                        )
                    self._dec_var.set("")
                self._dec_entry.pack_forget()
                self.set_thousand_sep()
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
                self._last_index = True
            self._dec_first_index = True
        else:
            self._dec_first_index = False

    def set_thousand_sep(self):
        if not (text:= self._int_var.get()):
            return
        sep = self._thousand_sep
        new_text = (f'{int(text.replace(self._thousand_sep, "")):,}'
                        .replace(",", self._thousand_sep)
                         )
        self._int_var.set(new_text)
        if (dif:= new_text.count(sep) - text.count(sep)) > 0:
            self._int_entry.icursor(self._int_entry.index(INSERT) + dif)

    def get(self):
        return decimal.Decimal(
            (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}"
             f".{self._dec_var.get()}")
            )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    # 3 - PASARLE LA VENTANA CREADA A LA CLASE PRODUCT COMO PARAMETRO(INSTANCIAR)
    aplication = Product(window)
    # 5 - EJECUTAR VENTANA
    window.mainloop()
```

----ESTRUCTURA TABLA product (nombre base de datos: database.db)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NUEVO ERROR:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PERSONAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 127, in add_product
    if self.validation():
  File "index5.py", line 122, in validation
    return len(self.name.get()) != 0  and len(self.price.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.section.get()) != 0
  File "index5.py", line 332, in get
    return decimal.Decimal(
NameError: name 'decimal' is not defined

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Hola Jose, ¿Cuál sería el formato de moneda que quieres exactamente? ¿Y el carácter para el separador? ¿O dependería de la localización del sistema que ejecute el código?

Comment: Hola amigo gracias. Creo que es mejor que dependa de la localización. Le agradezco mucho su ayuda con esos 2 puntos. Gracias.

Comment: Buenos dias amigo FJSevilla

Comment: Hola Jose, te comento, el primer punto es trivial, el segundo no tanto... Las localizaciones son un auténtico dolor de cabeza, hay países con varias monedas de curso legal, cada uno con un formato distinto (`-$45.23`, `$-45.23`, `-45.23 €`,`45.23 -€`, `(45.23) €`, etc, etc, etc). Si fuera un formato preestablecido sin depender de la localización también es simple p.e `$+-valor`. El tema de la separación de miles y separador de decimales si es fácil de resolver dependiendo de la localización, el tema de la moneda es más complejo.

Comment: Ok amigo comprendo. Bueno en ese caso y para no complicar mucho la cosa de momento, puede por favor colaborarme con lo de la mayuscula, y por lo menos aplicar un formato preestablecido cualquiera, usando mi codigo? es solo para saber como aplicarlo. Por favor, le agradezco.

Comment: Hola amigo, perdone,esta por ahi? Gracias

Comment: ayuda con esto por favor.

Comment: Hola Jose, perdona, no he tenido mucho tiempo éstos días. H creado una respuesta, la primera duda como comentaba es fácil de resolver, la segunda no tanto me temo, parece simple pero no lo es porque entra en juego factores humanos y del lenguaje natural.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema tiene una solución trivial, basta con usar el método str.upper en una callback enlazada con el evento `write` de una variable `StringVar` asociada al `Entry`:

```
var = tk.StringVar(frame)
self.name = Entry(frame, width=45, textvariable=var)
var.trace_add('write', lambda *args: var.set(var.get().upper()))
```

Aunque si se va a usar asiduamente, mejor crear nuestra propia clase:

```
class UpperEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self._var = kwargs.get("textvariable") or tk.StringVar(parent)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._to_upper()

    def config(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        self.configue(cnf, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        var = kwargs.get("textvariable")
        if var is not None:
            var.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = var
        super().config(cnf, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key == "textvariable":
            item.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = item
        super.__setitem__(key, item)

    def _to_upper(self, *args):
        self._var.set(self._var.get().upper())
```

y luego simplemente:

```
self.name = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
```

El formato de moneda es un tema aparte, es muy simple usando `locale` de la sdlib o bibliotecas como `babel` obtener a partir de un float su representación en moneda con separador de miles y símbolo y a la inversa, pero hacer ésto dinámicamente mientras el usaurio escribe en el `Entry` es mucho más complicado.

El problema no es solo la interacción en tiempo real, sino la graan cantidad de formas que hay de representar la moneda dependiendo de cada localización, muchas veces incluso con varias monedas de curso legal incluso.

Una opción es crear un widget propio, por composición, que separe cada componente parte decimal, fraccionaria, símbolo y signo y los maneje independientemente, pero que visualmente todo parezca uno. Es complejo, pero bien implementado es posiblemente la forma más robusta de hacer ésto. Dejo un ejemplo "básico":

```
import decimal
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class UpperEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self._var = kwargs.get("textvariable") or tk.StringVar(parent)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._to_upper()

    def config(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        self.configue(cnf, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        var = kwargs.get("textvariable")
        if var is not None:
            var.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = var
        super().config(cnf, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key == "textvariable":
            item.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = item
        super.__setitem__(key, item)

    def _to_upper(self, *args):
        self._var.set(self._var.get().upper())


class CurrencyEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(
            self, parent, *args,
            currency_symbol="€", thousand_sep=".", decimal_sep=",", **kwargs
            ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(
            highlightbackground="#000000", highlightcolor="#000000",
            highlightthickness=1, relief=tk.FLAT
            )
        self._int_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        self._dec_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        vcmd_int = (self.register(self.on_validate_int), '%S')
        vcmd_dec = (self.register(self.on_validate_dec), '%S')
        self._thousand_sep = thousand_sep
        self._decimal_sep = decimal_sep
        self._int_entry = tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._int_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_int,
            borderwidth=0, relief=tk.FLAT, justify='right',
            width=15, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._int_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x")

        self._dec_label = tk.Label(
            self, text=decimal_sep, relief=tk.FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._dec_entry = tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._dec_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_dec,
            borderwidth=0, relief=tk.FLAT, width=2,
            highlightthickness=0
        )

        self._sym_label = tk.Label(
            self, text=currency_symbol, relief=tk.FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._sym_label.pack(side="left")

        self._int_last_index = True
        self._dec_first_index = False
        self._int_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_int_release)
        self._dec_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_dec_release)

    def on_validate_int(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789" and char != self._decimal_sep:
            return False
        return True

    def on_validate_dec(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789":
            return False
        return True

    def _on_int_release(self, event):
        if self._int_entry.index(tk.INSERT) == self._int_entry.index(tk.END):
            if self._int_last_index and event.keysym == "Right":
                self._last_index = False
                self._dec_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._int_last_index = True
        else:
            self._int_last_index = False

        text = self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, "")
        if self._decimal_sep in text:
            int_, dec = text.split(self._decimal_sep)
            self._int_var.set(int_)
            self._sym_label.pack_forget()
            self._dec_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_entry.pack(side="left")
            self._sym_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_var.set(dec[:2])
            self._dec_entry.focus_set()
        self.set_thousand_sep()

    def _on_dec_release(self, event):
        key = event.keysym
        if key == "Left" and self._dec_entry.index(tk.INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_first_index = False
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._dec_first_index = True

        elif key == "BackSpace" and self._dec_entry.index(tk.INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_label.pack_forget()
                if self._dec_var.get() and int(self._dec_var.get()):
                    self._int_var.set(
                        self._int_var.get() + self._dec_var.get()
                        )
                    self._dec_var.set("")
                self._dec_entry.pack_forget()
                self.set_thousand_sep()
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
                self._last_index = True
            self._dec_first_index = True
        else:
            self._dec_first_index = False

    def set_thousand_sep(self):
        if not (text:= self._int_var.get()):
            return
        sep = self._thousand_sep
        new_text = (f'{int(text.replace(self._thousand_sep, "")):,}'
                        .replace(",", self._thousand_sep)
                         )
        self._int_var.set(new_text)
        if (dif:= new_text.count(sep) - text.count(sep)) > 0:
            self._int_entry.icursor(self._int_entry.index(tk.INSERT) + dif)

    def get(self):
        return decimal.Decimal(
            (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}"
             f".{self._dec_var.get()}")
            )


class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text=' REGISTRAR UN NUEVO PRODUCTO: ')
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=15, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        # INPUT NAME
        tk.Label(
            frame, text=' Nombre: '
            ).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.name = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        # INPUT PRECIO
        tk.Label(
            frame, text=' Precio: '
            ).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.price = CurrencyEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.price.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()
    Test(app).pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    app.mainloop()
```

Paara obtener el valor de un `CurrencyEntry` hay que lamar a su método `get`, retorna una instancia ade `decimal.Decimal` y no `float`, es importante evitar los errors de redondeo por la representación en coma flotante cunado se trabaja con moneda.

La clase está implementada para la respuesta con fines demostrativos sin un testeo adecuado y sin una implemntación completa (falta por implementar por ejemplo el poder copiar y pegar un valor). Tenerlo en cuenta y usar con cuidado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo de verdad y perdone que se que debe estar ocupado con sus cosas como es logico, voy a tratar de aplicar estos ejemplos y le comentare. Un millon de gracias.

Comment: Hola amigo como esta. Antes que todo gracias por su ayuda. Le comento que he agregado la clase "UpperEntry" a mi código y funcional genial, al igual que la clase "CurrencyEntry". Lo que no me funciona es cuando le doy clic en el botón "agregar producto", el cual llama a la función "add_product()". Sale un error al parecer con la función "decimal" de la clase "CurrencyEntry". Se que usted ne dijo que esta funcionalidad no estaba del todo testeada, pero aun así le agradezco si por lo menos puede revisar y ayudarme. Muchas gracias como siempre y perdone. Quedo atento.

Comment: PD: Arriba le dejo mi codigo actualizado en la pregunta prrincipal y abajo el error completo que me sale. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Jose, aparentemente te falta importar el módulo decimal (import decimal) al inicio de tu módulo dónde está dando el error. igual que en mi ejemplo. Puedes usar float en vez de decimal, pero debes tener en cuenta lo comentado sobre los errores de representación en coma flotante. Por cierto, el módulo re que antes lo importaba no hace falta, lo he quitado.

Comment: Para usar float sería cambiar la línea `return decimal.Decimal(
            (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}"
             f".{self._dec_var.get()}"))`
            por `return float(
            (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}"
             f".{self._dec_var.get()}")
            )` en el método `get` de `CurrencyEntry`

Comment: ya amigo, pero ahora me sale esto:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PERSONAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 127, in add_product
    if self.validation():
  File "index5.py", line 122, in validation
    return len(self.name.get()) != 0  and len(self.price.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.section.get()) != 0
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

***Repl Closed***

Comment: Deberías validar con `if self.price.get() != 0`, pero más fácil aún, si quieres una cadena como en un Entry normal simplemente en el método `get` de la clase retorna : `return (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}" f".{self._dec_var.get()}")`.

Comment: perdon amigo, ese ultimo pedazo de codigo donde lo debo colocar?

Comment: listo amigo, ya funciono. Gracias. Usted es un Máster. Ese símbolo de moneda Euro, porque esta al final del numero? porque no puede ir al comienzo? Es solo cuestión de diseño o eso tiene su lógica? Gracias.

Comment: Podrías ponerlo donde quieras, es cuestión de reorganizar la estructura de los widgets que componen la clase y colocar el Label del símboo al principio. Está al final porque en éste caso sigue la convención seguida en España, Portugal, Italia, Alemania, etc para la moneda `-+ num €`, con coma como separador decimal y punto como separador de miles. En USA, UK y gran parte de América efectivamente es `-+ $ num`, pero como ya comentaba antes esto es muy variable.

Comment: Listo amigo un millon de gracias, tengo otro problema con un treeview que estoy implementando, es de la misma aplicación que estoy haciendo. Ya monto la pregunta para que por favor me ayude como siempre. Gracias.